# Putting zeros in column except for the single row in the category in sql

Tags: sql, hive

Let's say I have a table that looks like that:

```
Name Category Subject Score

Alice 1 Math 2

Alice 1 Biology 3

Bob 2 Math 4

Bob 2 Biology 2
```

I would like to leave just one occurence of Score in each batch of Category for each Name and set rest to zero, so the result would be:

```
Alice 1 Math 2

Alice 1 Biology 0

Bob 2 Math 4

Bob 2 Biology 0
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: How do we know that, in the case of Alice, biology comes before math?

Comment: how are you determining which is 'first'?

Comment: Records are un-ordered in a table, so how can do define "first occurrence of Score"?

Comment: first in data source order

Comment: it's not even about being first, it is about leaving just one score in each category

Comment: Do you want to execute a query or an update command?

Comment: So you want all set to zero except one and it doesn't matter which? Please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: @Stu yes exactly